# Сообщение Denwer: it works

Tags: denwer

Помогите, запускаю денвер, всё нормально, пишу localhost тоже, но когда открывается localhost, у меня написано "it works", а не ура заработала?

Comment: В чем вопрос? it work это можно приравнять к УРА ЗАРАБОТАЛО. Все работает! Или я чего то не понял?

Answer (score 4):

Видимо, в папочке, на которую отзывается localhost, индексный файл нужно заменить на любой необходимый...